# I cannot log in to the system FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd

When I write reboot, computer says;

> login:
>
> password:

and I wrote these. Then the Welcome message comes to me. Login screen does not open. Like this:

> Welcome to freeBSD!
>
> Release notes, Errate htps://ww......
>
> Security etc....
>
> Documents installed with the system are in the
>   /usr/local/share/doc/freebsd/directory, or can be installed later
>   with: pkg install en-freebsd-doc. For other languages, replace ''en''
>   with a language code like de or fr.
>
> Edit /etc/motd to change this login announcement.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I understand correctly, but... do you mean that only console is available and there's nothing with UI on screen?

If so, you have to install/launch desktop environment first:
https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/x11-wm.html

Comment: Yes, you got it right. Now, i tried  pkg install gnome3, but console said .. insufficient privileges to install..

Comment: @B.Ozen, you usually have to be logged in as root to be able to install packages

Answer (score 1):

Based on your description, and contrary to the title of your question, you *have* successfully logged-in.

> Login screen does not open.

In all likelihood, you are referring to **Graphical User Interface** (GUI) not appearing... Well, why would it? FreeBSD does not have GUI as part of the OS itself -- you'd have to install that separately...

Answer (score 0):

When you installed FreeBSD you were asked for a root password and for adding more users, check the [post-installation](https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/bsdinstall-post.html) guide, therefore you need to use either the user you added or the root password.

In case you are using a custom image something like [fabrik.red](https://fabrik.red/post/default-user/) the username and password may differ.

In case you need to reset the root password check this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xzk_U9E9jQU